# How do I make a listener that fires when the USER selects an item in a JComboBox

Tags: java, events, jcombobox

I'm looking for a listener that fires ONLY when the user, the one who's using the program, selects an item in the `JComboBox`. I don't want to use `ActionListener` or `ItemListener` because those also fire when I select an item through the program. And I can't use `MouseListener` either because it only fires when I click the `JComboBox`, not when I select an item.

I was wondering what the easiest way to do this is? Currently, my solution is messy. When I change the selected item of the jcombobox through code, I set a flag to true. And in my action listener, it only executes if the flag is false.

Comment: When I change the selected item of the jcombobox through code, I set a flag to true. And in my action listener, it only executes if the flag is false. - I have had to do this in several cases, Id also like to know a less kludgey way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

A) I would recommend you to temporarily remove the listener when you perform the selection programatically.

B) If your programatic change is not an effect of another GUI event you could solve it the following ugly/non-robust/error-prone/"hacky" way: Check `EventQueue.isEventDispatchThread()` to find out if the click was triggered by the GUI thread (the user).

C) *(Oops I just reread your question and saw that you've already discovered the method described below. Basically I would say that this (or the the method described above) is your best alternative.)*

Another option is to have a boolean flag called something like `nonUserSelection` which you set to true before you select a value programatically and reset to false afterwards. In the action listener you simply add an

```
if (nonUserSelection)
    return;
```

Comment: It is an effect of another GUI event. What I'm doing is having 2 comboboxes placed by each other. When user selects something in the first one, it gets selected in the second one unless the user has already selected something in that one.